# M2.3.5 | compilation error: Incompatible argument type "ResolverInterface-Emulation"

Tags: compilation

I found similar questions but not my argument, can someone please find what error is this?

```
 Errors during compilation:
        Emagicone\Mobassistantconnector\Helper\PdfInvoice
                Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation. Actual type: \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface; File:
/home/scontoli/public_html/app/code/Emagicone/Mobassistantconnector/Helper/PdfInvoice.php
```

here's my file **PdfInvoice.php**

```
<?php
/**
 *    This file is part of Mobile Assistant Connector.
 *
 *   Mobile Assistant Connector is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 *   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 *   the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 *   (at your option) any later version.
 *
 *   Mobile Assistant Connector is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 *   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 *   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 *   GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 *   You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 *   along with Mobile Assistant Connector.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */

namespace Emagicone\Mobassistantconnector\Helper;

use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Config;

/**
 * Class PdfInvoice
 * @package Emagicone\Mobassistantconnector\Helper
 */
class PdfInvoice extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice
{
    protected $_paymentData;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param Config $pdfConfig
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Factory $pdfTotalFactory
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        Config $pdfConfig,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Factory $pdfTotalFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_paymentData = $paymentData;
        parent::__construct(
            $paymentData,
            $string,
            $scopeConfig,
            $filesystem,
            $pdfConfig,
            $pdfTotalFactory,
            $pdfItemsFactory,
            $localeDate,
            $inlineTranslation,
            $addressRenderer,
            $storeManager,
            $localeResolver,
            $data
        );
    }

    /**
     * Insert order to pdf page
     *
     * @param \Zend_Pdf_Page &$page
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $obj
     * @param bool $putOrderId
     * @return void
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    protected function insertOrder(&$page, $obj, $putOrderId = true)
    {
        if ($obj instanceof \Magento\Sales\Model\Order) {
            $shipment = null;
            $order = $obj;
        } elseif ($obj instanceof \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment) {
            $shipment = $obj;
            $order = $shipment->getOrder();
        }

        $this->y = $this->y ? $this->y : 815;
        $top = $this->y;

        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.45));
        $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.45));
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $top, 570, $top - 55);
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));
        $this->setDocHeaderCoordinates([25, $top, 570, $top - 55]);
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);

        if ($putOrderId) {
            $page->drawText(__('Order # ') . $order->getRealOrderId(), 35, $top -= 30, 'UTF-8');
        }
        $page->drawText(
            __('Order Date: ') .
            $this->_localeDate->formatDate(
                $this->_localeDate->scopeDate(
                    $order->getStore(),
                    $order->getCreatedAt(),
                    true
                ),
                \IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM,
                false
            ),
            35,
            $top -= 15,
            'UTF-8'
        );

        $top -= 10;
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
        $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
        $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $top, 275, $top - 25);
        $page->drawRectangle(275, $top, 570, $top - 25);

        /* Calculate blocks info */

        /* Billing Address */
        $billingAddress = $this->_formatAddress($this->addressRenderer->format($order->getBillingAddress(), 'pdf'));

        /* Payment */
        $paymentInfo = $this->_paymentData->getInfoBlock($order->getPayment())->setIsSecureMode(true);
        $paymentInfo->setData('area', \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML);
        $paymentInfo = $paymentInfo->toPdf();
        $paymentInfo = htmlspecialchars_decode($paymentInfo, ENT_QUOTES);
        $payment = explode('{{pdf_row_separator}}', $paymentInfo);
        foreach ($payment as $key => $value) {
            if (strip_tags(trim($value)) == '') {
                unset($payment[$key]);
            }
        }
        reset($payment);

        /* Shipping Address and Method */
        if (!$order->getIsVirtual()) {
            /* Shipping Address */
            $shippingAddress = $this->_formatAddress($this->addressRenderer->format($order->getShippingAddress(), 'pdf'));
            $shippingMethod = $order->getShippingDescription();
        }

        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
        $this->_setFontBold($page, 12);
        $page->drawText(__('Sold to:'), 35, $top - 15, 'UTF-8');

        if (!$order->getIsVirtual()) {
            $page->drawText(__('Ship to:'), 285, $top - 15, 'UTF-8');
        } else {
            $page->drawText(__('Payment Method:'), 285, $top - 15, 'UTF-8');
        }

        $addressesHeight = $this->_calcAddressHeight($billingAddress);
        if (isset($shippingAddress)) {
            $addressesHeight = max($addressesHeight, $this->_calcAddressHeight($shippingAddress));
        }

        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $top - 25, 570, $top - 33 - $addressesHeight);
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
        $this->y = $top - 40;
        $addressesStartY = $this->y;

        foreach ($billingAddress as $value) {
            if ($value !== '') {
                $text = [];
                foreach ($this->string->split($value, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                    $text[] = $_value;
                }
                foreach ($text as $part) {
                    $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($part)), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
                    $this->y -= 15;
                }
            }
        }

        $addressesEndY = $this->y;

        if (!$order->getIsVirtual()) {
            $this->y = $addressesStartY;
            foreach ($shippingAddress as $value) {
                if ($value !== '') {
                    $text = [];
                    foreach ($this->string->split($value, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                        $text[] = $_value;
                    }
                    foreach ($text as $part) {
                        $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($part)), 285, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
                        $this->y -= 15;
                    }
                }
            }

            $addressesEndY = min($addressesEndY, $this->y);
            $this->y = $addressesEndY;

            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
            $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
            $page->drawRectangle(25, $this->y, 275, $this->y - 25);
            $page->drawRectangle(275, $this->y, 570, $this->y - 25);

            $this->y -= 15;
            $this->_setFontBold($page, 12);
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
            $page->drawText(__('Payment Method'), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
            $page->drawText(__('Shipping Method:'), 285, $this->y, 'UTF-8');

            $this->y -= 10;
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));

            $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));

            $paymentLeft = 35;
            $yPayments = $this->y - 15;
        } else {
            $yPayments = $addressesStartY;
            $paymentLeft = 285;
        }

        foreach ($payment as $value) {
            if (trim($value) != '') {
                //Printing "Payment Method" lines
                $value = preg_replace('/<br[^>]*>/i', "\n", $value);
                foreach ($this->string->split($value, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                    $page->drawText(strip_tags(trim($_value)), $paymentLeft, $yPayments, 'UTF-8');
                    $yPayments -= 15;
                }
            }
        }

        if ($order->getIsVirtual()) {
            // replacement of Shipments-Payments rectangle block
            $yPayments = min($addressesEndY, $yPayments);
            $page->drawLine(25, $top - 25, 25, $yPayments);
            $page->drawLine(570, $top - 25, 570, $yPayments);
            $page->drawLine(25, $yPayments, 570, $yPayments);

            $this->y = $yPayments - 15;
        } else {
            $topMargin = 15;
            $methodStartY = $this->y;
            $this->y -= 15;

            foreach ($this->string->split($shippingMethod, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                $page->drawText(strip_tags(trim($_value)), 285, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
                $this->y -= 15;
            }

            $yShipments = $this->y;
            $totalShippingChargesText = "(" . __(
                    'Total Shipping Charges'
                ) . " " . $order->formatPriceTxt(
                    $order->getShippingAmount()
                ) . ")";

            $page->drawText($totalShippingChargesText, 285, $yShipments - $topMargin, 'UTF-8');
            $yShipments -= $topMargin + 10;

            $tracks = [];
            if ($shipment) {
                $tracks = $shipment->getAllTracks();
            }
            if (count($tracks)) {
                $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
                $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
                $page->drawRectangle(285, $yShipments, 510, $yShipments - 10);
                $page->drawLine(400, $yShipments, 400, $yShipments - 10);
                //$page->drawLine(510, $yShipments, 510, $yShipments - 10);

                $this->_setFontRegular($page, 9);
                $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
                //$page->drawText(__('Carrier'), 290, $yShipments - 7 , 'UTF-8');
                $page->drawText(__('Title'), 290, $yShipments - 7, 'UTF-8');
                $page->drawText(__('Number'), 410, $yShipments - 7, 'UTF-8');

                $yShipments -= 20;
                $this->_setFontRegular($page, 8);
                foreach ($tracks as $track) {
                    $maxTitleLen = 45;
                    $endOfTitle = strlen($track->getTitle()) > $maxTitleLen ? '...' : '';
                    $truncatedTitle = substr($track->getTitle(), 0, $maxTitleLen) . $endOfTitle;
                    $page->drawText($truncatedTitle, 292, $yShipments, 'UTF-8');
                    $page->drawText($track->getNumber(), 410, $yShipments, 'UTF-8');
                    $yShipments -= $topMargin - 5;
                }
            } else {
                $yShipments -= $topMargin - 5;
            }

            $currentY = min($yPayments, $yShipments);

            // replacement of Shipments-Payments rectangle block
            $page->drawLine(25, $methodStartY, 25, $currentY);
            //left
            $page->drawLine(25, $currentY, 570, $currentY);
            //bottom
            $page->drawLine(570, $currentY, 570, $methodStartY);
            //right

            $this->y = $currentY;
            $this->y -= 15;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely the arguments are in the wrong order in the `parent::__construct(...)` the need to be in the same order as the parent class.

Comment: I tried to disable the module but error is still present. How possible is this?

Comment: Di:compile doesn't check the magento enabled/disabled status when it checks the files. If it's in the file system it can error. You'd be better getting the developer of the module to fix the error